# Is there any way to check the liveness of a IMessageSender connection in Azure Service Bus?

Tags: azure

I want to check whether the connection is open or not. Basically like a function that returns a boolean.
Is there any type of function supported by the Azure service bus?

I am using [Service bus SDK 3.5.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/servicebus/client?view=azure-java-stable&preserve-view=true)

Comment: you can check active connections from the metrics

Comment: Thanks, @Sajeetharan. How to check this programmatically.  I am using Java SDK.

Comment: you can access using the SDK https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/monitor-service-bus-reference#connection-metrics